# How to enable crossfire on AMD Radeon Pro DUO

Tags: gpu, opencl, amd-gpu

I am using AMD Radeon Pro duo for my application in opencl.
It has a Dual Fiji GPUs, How can i configure Cross Fire to make them work as one device. I am using clgetdeviceinfo in opencl for checking the device compute units but it's showing 64 for each fiji GPU.

I have total 128 compute units in two GPUS, How to use all of them by using Crossfire.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCL has device fission but not device fusion. Devices can share memory for efficiency but shaders can't be joined.

There are also some functions that can't synchronize between two GPUs yet:

- Atomic functions in kernels
- Prefetch command(which GPUs global cache?)
- clEnqueueAcquireGLObject(which GPU's buffer?)
- clCreateBuffer (which device memorry does it choose? we can't choose.)
- clEnqueueTask (where does this task go?)

You should partition the encoding work in two pieces and run on both GPUs. This may even need cross-fire to be disabled if drivers have problems with it. This shouldn't be harder than writing a GPGPU encoder.

But you may need to copy data to only one of the devices, then copy half of data to other GPU from that buffer, instead of passing through pci-e twice. The inter-GPU connection must be faster than pci-e.